# Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 : jarsigner:

Tags: java, android

I got this error when I try to create a signed app. I had my keystore backup in the cloud and in my hard drive. I used my existing keystore with correct alias and passwords. But it gives this error and couldn't complete the signing process:->

Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 : jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: key().  key() must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Note:- I had to reinstall android studio in my computer and reset it's setting before as autocomplete was not working in all my project.

Please help